# Linq to Excel with multiple tabs

Tags: c#, linq, excel

I use  Entity Framework together with Linq to fill my gridviews.
I would like to get the same data I get from the Linq in an excel.
Also a second tab in the same excel sheet should come from another Linq query.

Whats the easiest and best way to do this?

Comment: I like http://epplus.codeplex.com/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are two parts to this. The first is to serialise your linq collection to CSV. You can serialise an enumerable method like this:

```
public static string ToCsv<T>(string separator, IEnumerable<T> objectlist)
{
    Type t = typeof(T);
    FieldInfo[] fields = t.GetFields();

    string header = String.Join(separator, fields.Select(f => f.Name).ToArray());

    StringBuilder csvdata = new StringBuilder();
    csvdata.AppendLine(header);

    foreach (var o in objectlist) 
        csvdata.AppendLine(ToCsvFields(separator, fields, o));

    return csvdata.ToString();
}
```

That method won't help you with deep objects but it will get you to CSV. The second stage is to build the XSLX format (assuming that 2 CSVs won't be enough). For that I would recommend [the Open XML SDK](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb448854%28office.14%29.aspx) from Microsoft to build the two worksheets from your CSV string. I also like [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/151005/create-excel-xls-and-xlsx-file-from-c-sharp) for building an Excel spreadsheet.